# Agregar comas en forma automática en un imput

Tags: javascript

Cómo podría hacer para que al introducir palabras en un input, y al darle enter, se agregue una "coma (,)" entre las palabras que vaya colocando?

```
     <input type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control form-control-md" 
      placeholder="Agregar" value="" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando javascript solo tienes que cambiar el input y ponerle una id (`<input type="text" name="post_tags" class="form-control form-control-md"  placeholder="Agregar" value="" required id="comainput">`) y añadir este codigo de javascript a la web:

```
const input = document.getElementById('comainput');

input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        input.value += ', ';
    }
});
```

Lo que hace es que cuando pulsas INTRO añade una coma a el *input*

Comment: Muchas gracias!